# Create image from BLOB using ImageIO?

Tags: java, image, blob

I tried to create image from BLOB.  I try following code but it is not working at step:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", iio);)
```

`image` is `null`.  Please give me any suggestion.

```
 byte[] imgData = null;
 if (rs.next ())
 {
   Blob img  = rs.getBlob(1);
   imgData = img.getBytes(1,(int)img.length());
   File f1 = new File(fillFilePath); //fillFilePath = path where image want to store
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgData));
   ImageOutputStream iio = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(f1);
   ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", iio);
 }
```

How to create image from BLOB using ImageIO?

Comment: Please include *full error messages* (copy'n'paste) and *stack traces* (when relevant). Just be reading them, a whole host of problems can be quickly reduced in complexity and causes can be deduced.

Comment: @pst  *"(when relevant)."*  In cases where the question boils down to "Why is my code broken?", when is the stack trace ***not*** relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JavaDoc on `ImageIO.read(InputStream)`:

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.

It seems your blob doesn't represent an image format that `ImageIO` is able to understand. What format does the image stored in the blob have?

Comment: Maybe so, but then it should be failing at the code line *before* the one indicated by the OP.

Comment: @Andrew not according to the JavaDoc. Since the image readers can't understand the image format they just ignore it. Thus the image is null. Basically `ImageIO.getImageReaders()` will return an interator for an empty set. It won't throw an exception and thus a return value of `null` means the input isn't understood.

Comment: @Andrew btw, the image isn't involved at all in the line `ImageOutputStream iio = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(f1);` since just an output stream is created. That might be done even _before_ trying to read the image, since only the file `f1` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me. I am able to retrieve BLOB(oracle)/binary(hive) from hive:

```
InputStream is=rs.getBinaryStream(1);

toImage(is,"C:\\hive_image.png");

public void toImage(InputStream is,String imagePath) throws IOException
{

    BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(is);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File(imagePath));

}
```